# How to save user's input in variable using delegate?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tableview

I'm making ios app. Please look my table view image below.

[image]

If you click add(+) button, you can add ENG word and its meaning in Korean(KOR) in each textfield.

[image]

After filling the textfield and click save button (it is located on right-top, "저장"), the word is added like the image below.

[word is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBgtn.png)

For example, the ENG is endless and the meaning(KOR) is "끝없는".

And, I want to use UIReferenceLibraryViewController .
If i click the cell of the list, i want to show its dictionary.

```
@IBAction func viewDictionary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let engDictionaryWord = **engListWord**
        let ViewController = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: engDictionaryWord)
        self.present(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I want to use this method.
But, I don't know how to save my ENG input in **engListWord**.

In pic2 's swift file(addWordViewController.swift), there is prepare() method like this.

```
// This method lets you configure a view controller before it's presented.
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    // Configure the destination view controller only when the save button is pressed.
    guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button === saveButton else {
        os_log("The save button was not pressed, cancelling", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return
    }

    let eng = engTextField.text ?? ""
    let kor = korTextField.text ?? ""

    // Set the meal to be passed to WordTableViewController after the unwind segue.
    word = Word(eng:eng, kor:kor)
}
```

and viewDidLoad() method in addWordViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    engTextField.delegate = self
    korTextField.delegate = self

    // Set up views if editing an existing Word.
    if let word = word{
        engTextField.text = word.eng
        korTextField.text = word.kor
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I don't know which variable i have to use.
There is other swift file in my project, If i misuploaded that codes above, please tell me! I will edit my question immediately.

[image]

Main.Storyboard

[image]

If i use GestureRecognizer, i made this code but I don't know it is right...

```
@IBAction func MyDictionary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "viewDictionary", sender: indexPath)
    }

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // I just made this identifier up, but create one yourself in the storyboard
        if segue.identifier == "viewDictionary" {
            // Define your vc
            let libController = segue.destination as! UIReferenceLibraryViewController

            // Define indexPath
            let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath

            // Set value in destination vc
            libController.engWord = words[indexPath.row].eng
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question. When you press a table view cell containing both the English and Korean word you want to save the words?

Comment: @matiastofteby When i press a table view cell, I want to show the dictionary page using UIReferenceLibraryViewController. To use UIReferenceLibraryViewController, ENG is only necessary thing. 

So, when i add new word, i want to save an ENG text, and use it with  UIReferenceLibraryViewController code. But, I can't save ENG text. 

To use UIReferenceLibraryViewController, I have to save each ENG text in **engListWord**

Comment: @matiastofteby In short, I want to save English text of each table view cell.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. Do you want to save all English words no matter which cell the user presses or just the word from the pressed cell?

Comment: @matiastofteby Umm.. actually, Without saving the all word, if I can use UIReferenceLibraryViewController, it is OK.

Comment: @matiastofteby To use UIReferenceLibraryViewController, as you can see above, i must give the ENG word in variable(?) **engListWord**. But, I am having difficulty saving a cell's english word. Because word is saved in other swift file like addWordViewController.swift . I have to use that word in WordTableViewController.swift

Comment: So, I have to copy(?) or move(?) written english word to another swift file! How can i do it?

Comment: Ok last question. I assume you save the your words that you fill the tableviewcells with in an array? Can you show me that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way to go is to use the `UITableViewDelegate` method `didSelectRowAtindexPath` in the WordTableViewController (if that's the class with your table view).

A gestureRecognizer does not seem like something you want in your tableViewController as it has nice build in delegate methods to register user presses. Therefore, replace your viewDictionary(_:) function with the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "viewDictionary", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // I just made this identifier up, but create one yourself in the storyboard
    if segue.identifier == "viewDictionary" {
       // Define your vc
       let libController = segue.destination as! UIReferenceLibraryViewController

       // Define indexPath
       let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath

       // Set value in destination vc
       libController.engWord = yourArrayOfEngWords[indexPath.row]       
    }
}
```

This will get your eng word of the cell you have pressed and save it to an attribute "engWord" that you then define in your `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`:

```
class UIReferenceLibraryViewController(){
     var engWord: String = ""

     // Rest your class properties and functions here...
}
```

Once it is set you can use it as you like after the segue has been performed :=)

Comment: Should i make new swift file named UIReferenceLibraryViewController ?

Comment: I made new cocoa touch class name UIReferenceLibraryViewController. But... there is a new error...

Comment: WordTableViewController.swift:80:42: Cannot assign value of type 'Word' to type 'String'

Comment: I use this code to save my words. I think it is not just an array...T.T
    var words = [Word]()

Comment: It is array + dictionary I think... right? in addWordViewController.swift, I wrote this code... word = Word(eng:eng, kor:kor)

Comment: Yes you mentioned the UIReferenceLibraryViewController so I assumed you had created a class. No "Word" is your own class so String can not be applied -> just change the type to Word if you want to use that. 
And you are right - then you'll have to pass the word in stead.

Comment: @matiasofteby thanks! I solved it by changing word[indexPath.row] to word[indexPath.row].eng!! But... how can i make to show up the dictionary page by clicking table view's cell? I was about to use gestureRecognizer to do that...

Comment: Delete the IBAction function completely you do not need a IBAction for a user press because when implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` the `didSelectRowAtindexPath` will be where you can access your row using index path thus simplifying things drastically.

Comment: Do you mean GestureRecognizer IBAction? I deleted it. I cannot understand what is implementing the UITableViewDelegate the didSelectRowAtindexPath ... Should i add the code ..? now, there is no reaction when i click my cell.

Comment: I think you'll be better off trying to follow a simple tutorial like [this one](http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/#UITableViewDelegate). This one is for beginners and neatly explains the basics of tableviewdelegates and cells.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it. have a nice day!